# Book about a fantasy world where the more runes you have, the stronger you are, and the nobility have loads

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

When I was a kid, I remember reading a book about this fantasy world where you can be imbued with runes. I apologize if this is vague but I will jot down some memories I have of it:

1. The more runes you are imbued with the stronger you are.
2. The nobility have loads of runes.
3. There's specifically a scene where I remember a noble fighting a cyclops or some similar creature and his immense amount of runes made it easy for him to win.

Does this match anything? Or is my brain making up a book?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book, and do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: What language was it in?

Comment: The theme here seems very similar to Duncan's *A Man of His Word*, but in that story people don't have "loads" of words, the most powerful people have 3 or 4.

Comment: I don't think there are any cyclops in the Runelords series, but you say "cyclops or some similar creature" so I guess it might not be a cyclops. Can you remember any more details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be ***[The Runelords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Runelords)*** (1998) by David Farland...?

> *The Runelords* is a series of fantasy novels by American author David Farland of which the first part was published in 1998. In the universe of The Runelords, there exists a unique magical system which relies on the existence of distinct bodily attributes, such as brawn, grace, and wit. These attributes can be transferred from one individual (or animal) to another in a process known as "giving an endowment". Lords who have taken many endowments become extremely powerful, almost superhuman, and are known as Runelords.

Comment: I came here to suggest just this answer - I only read the first book (_The Sum of All Men_) so I don't remember a Runelord fighting a cyclops, but the rest of it is spot on.

Comment: That would have been my answer, too.

Comment: This sounds fairly close to what I was thinking so it may very well be this